# Rhomobile: Custom URL Schemes

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I'm writing a Rhomobile application targeted at iPhone and Android.
I need to create a custom url scheme, so that i can create urls that look like `test://some-params` that will launch my program and will pass it the params.

As far as I understand this is done in build.yml through the BundleURLScheme parameter, and then System.get_start_params() to get those parameters.
However, this works on the iPhone only as far as I understand.
Is there any way to make this work on Android too?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKay, I've found the answer myself, in case anybody needs this too:

- Create an extension to the application as explained here:
  http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/extensions#generating-a-native-extension-template
- Add an android_manifest_changes file, as decribed in the above link.
- In that file add the following lines:

  ```
  <manifest xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
  android:versionName='1.0' package='com.rhomobile.webbrowserpoc'
  android:versionCode='10000' android:installLocation='auto'>
  <application android:name='com.rhomobile.rhodes.RhodesApplication'
      android:label='@string/app_name' android:icon='@drawable/icon'
      android:debuggable='true'>
      <activity android:name='com.rhomobile.rhodes.RhodesActivity'
          android:label='@string/app_name' android:launchMode='singleTask'
          android:configChanges='orientation|keyboardHidden'
          android:screenOrientation='unspecified'>
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name='android.intent.action.VIEW' />
              <category android:name='android.intent.category.BROWSABLE' />
              <category android:name='android.intent.category.DEFAULT' />
              <data android:pathPrefix='' android:scheme=''
                  android:host='' />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
  </application>
  ```

Only the `<data android:pathPrefix='' android:scheme='' android:host='' />` line should be filled in with correct properties.